# Why do Ceva's/Menelaus's Theorem fail here?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, euclidean-geometry

This is based on [another geometry question here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4064845/geometry-length-of-triangle-question/4065236#4065236). Note that I could obtain the correct answer, but I'm not sure where the errors are in the following attempt.

---

[image]
(Note: $\lvert OA\rvert=f$)

By Ceva's and Menelaus's, we have
$$\frac{3+x}{x}\cdot\frac{e}{f}\cdot\frac{d}{c}=1\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{x+2}{2}\cdot\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{f}{e}=1\tag{2}$$
$$\frac{3}{x}\cdot\frac{a}{b}\cdot\frac{d}{c}=1\tag{3}$$

Eliminating $a,b,c,d,e,f$ (by dividing $(1)$ by $(3)$ and multiply by $(2)$) will end up with $x=0 \text{ or}-5$, which are nonsensical solutions.

Other attempts of utilizing $e,f$ have also ended up with other weird solutions, which I'll not post here to save space.

Comment: What are $e,f$? If $f = AO$, $(2)$ is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, that's it! I should have spotted it. Thanks @player3236.

Comment: Name the intersection of line segments with lengths $a$ and $b$ as $X$. To be able to apply Menelaus' Theorem in Eq. (2),  points $C, X,$  and $O$ should be collinear.

Comment: Even equation $1$ does not seem correct. It should be $\frac{3+x}{x}\cdot\frac{e}{f}\cdot\frac{b}{a}=1\tag{1}$

Comment: A theorem cannot fail, only an application of it...